# Work done in an Adiabatic Process

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

[image: Air compressor problem]

My question is, where did they get the equation of work done? So far I know only one equation: $W=\dfrac{mR\left(T_1-T_2\right)}{\gamma-1}$

Comment: Probably comes from Q - W = Delta U

Comment: The starting equation for mechanical work is $w = \int p_{ext} dV$. Substitute in the terms to apply for reversible and adiabatic processes.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is about an adiabatic process?  It looks to me more like it's about a general polytropic process.  Either way, if you've got an equation for work done in terms of temperature, you can use $pv^n =$ constant and the ideal gas law $pv = RT$ to rewrite it in terms of pressure.

Comment: @DanielHatton Yes. This is a polytropic process. I was wrong. But, I cannot get the equation in the image with the two equations you mentioned. I am getting an equation like this $W=mRT_1\dfrac{1}{1-n}\left[\left(\dfrac{P_2}{P_1}\right)^\dfrac{n-1}{n}-1\right]$ from $W=\int_{1}^{n}PdV$.

Comment: Ideal gas law gives $T_2/T_1 = p_2v_2/\left(p_1v_1\right)$.  Polytropic law gives $v_2/v_1 = \left(p_1/p_2\right)^{1/n}$, so $T_2/T_1 = \left(p_2/p_1\right)^{1-1/n} = \left(p_2/p_1\right)^{\left(n-1\right)/n}$.  So if you already have a formula that says the work done is $mR\left(T_2-T_1\right)/\left(1-n\right) = mRT_1\left(T_2/T_1-1\right)/\left(1-n\right)$, you can substitute in to get $mRT_1\left(\left(p_2/p_1\right)^{\left(n-1\right)/n}-1\right)/\left(1-n\right)$.

Comment: @DanielHatton According to you, the work done would be, $mRT_1\left(\dfrac{1}{1-n}\right)\left[\left(\dfrac{P_2}{P_1}\right)^\dfrac{n-1}{n}-1\right]$. But why did the answer show an extra $n$ for the numerator like $\dfrac{n}{1-n}$?

Comment: @Fahad Maybe it's a flow process and that factor of $n$ is taking account of the energy transfer ("work", but not part of the "work done during compression") associated with a moving fluid that has different pressures in front of it and behind it?

Comment: Normally, that would be a factor of $\gamma$ (mathematically equivalent to all the other energy transfers matching change in enthalpy instead of change in internal energy), but in this case, the maintenance of polytropicity means that there would be an extra heat transfer locked to that extra work transfer.